# Accesing function within function JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, dry

I got this piece of code below which is not DRY. What i want to do is to cut it,so everything below var = text would be used only once not twice.

My concept is,to close these two functions in bigger function (e.g. guess()) and keep trimmed correctGuess() and incorrectGuess() within it.

Now here's the question,how can I call such nested function as describe above from outside scope. I was thinking about smth like: guess().correctGuess() which is obviously wrong but I wanted to share a concept.

Additionally, when e.g. correctGuess() would be called, is rest of the commands within our main guess() function would be executed?

```
function correctGuess(i) {

    totalScore++;
    questionNumber++;

    var text = "Correct!";

    var updatePage = ['<div id="answerDiv">' +
        '<h1>' + text + '<h1>' +
        '<h2>Total Score: ' + totalScore + '</h2></div>'
    ];

    mainContent[html](updatePage);

    $('#answerDiv')[fadeIn]("slow");
    $('#answerDiv').append('<button id="nextButton">Next Question</button>');

    $('#nextButton').on('click', function() {
        if (questionNumber == allQuestions.length && totalScore <= 4) {
            results()
        } else {
            question(questionNumber)
        }
    })
};

var incorrectGuess = function(i) {
    totalScore--;
    questionNumber++;

    var text = "Wrong!";

    var updatePage = ['<div id="answerDiv">' +
        '<h1>' + text + '<h1>' +
        '<h2>Total Score: ' + totalScore + '</h2></div>'
    ];

    mainContent[html](updatePage);

    $('#answerDiv')[fadeIn]("slow");
    $('#answerDiv').append('<button id="nextButton">Next Question</button>');

    $('#nextButton').on('click', function() {
        if (questionNumber == allQuestions.length && totalScore <= 4) {
            results();
        } else {
            question(questionNumber);
        }

    });

};
```

Comment: Create a third, shared function that is declared outside your two functions, but can be called from within both.  Pass it whatever data it needs as arguments.

Comment: Or, make everything a single function where you pass it a boolean for correct or incorrect guess so almost all the code can be common and the little bit of different code uses `if (correct)` statements to decide which behavior.

Comment: FYI, if this code works and your entire question is really how to DRY this up, then you should probably post in http://codereview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: I think this could be good for our Code Review site, though I might suggest to reword your question so as not so much to ask "How to do *X*" as this would be off-topic as "Code not written yet" per CR guidelines.

Comment: @jfriend00 Hey,even the DRY tag return to StackExchange,I'll give it a try :)

Answer (score -2):

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_objects.asp

From your question it seems like you aren't very familiar with object notation. Read up on the above link and then try to create a js "guess" object with 2 member functions. Correct and Incorrect guess.

Comment: Its obvious that they are new to Object Oriented Notation and they are confused. I'm not sure that stating so and not providing any explanatory code and just saying "your doing it wrong, go read more" is helpful at all.

Comment: I know i can divide this into three functions but i wanted to give it a try and turn it into an object for learning purposes. I know js objects in theory but in practice they're more intimidating ;)

Answer (score -2):

You need to use the `this` keyword.

```
function guess(){
  /* do stuff here for guess() */
  this.correct = function(){
    /* Do stuff for correct */
  }
  this.wrong = function(){
    /* Do stuff for wrong */
  }
  return this;
}
```

Because you returned `this` you can now access the `correct()` and `wrong()` functions using:

```
guess().correct();
// AND
guess().wrong();
```

Note that whatever code you write inside guess() and outside the two nested functions will also be called every time you call `guess().correct()` or `guess().wrong()`

If you do not want any particular code to execute every time they "guess" regardless of right or wrong then I would suggest just storing the `correct()` and `wrong()` functions in an object literal.

```
var guess = {
  correct: function(){
    // Code for "correct" here
  },
  wrong: function(){
    // Code for "wrong" here
  }
}
```

And then you can access them using

```
guess.correct();
// AND
guess.wrong();
```

Comment: Hey,how much I would want, but these syntaxes are wrong but they've gave me a good direction where to head :)

Comment: These syntaxes are not wrong, not to say there are not other object oriented syntaxes out there, but these are in no way incorrect

Comment: The first example is definitely wrong. Unless you call `new guess()` you'll end up just binding those methods to the `window`.

Comment: Did you try it? Because the prototype returns ``this`` it works just fine. Maybe you should actually try the code before you try and tell me it doesn't work. http://codepen.io/dustinpoissant/pen/NPyqoe?editors=101